# When using terraform to create aws_ses_domain_identity, how do you add tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ses

I have the terraform

```
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "example_co_uk" {
  domain = "example.co.uk"
}
```

Which I can use to create a verified identity in SES. The AWS Console has a tab for adding tags manually but if I add the tags argument, as documented here [Tagging](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging):

```
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "example_co_uk" {
  domain = "example.co.uk"

  tags = {
    Squad = "Foobar"
  }
}
```

When running the verification or plan fails with the error:

```
An argument named "tags" is not expected here
```

The docs for [aws_ses_domain_identity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ses_email_identity) do not mention tags and so I was wondering how I specify them using terraform.

Comment: This resource does not support tagging that way. You can try adding this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging#propagating-tags-to-all-resources. But if the resource does not support it it won't be there.

Comment: Frustrating, but many thanks for having a look